# html image issue on wordpress site in explorer only

Tags: html, wordpress, internet-explorer

I am trying to fix some issues on a clients site. The developer who was working on it quit so I ve had to jump in and start fixing his mess.
The problem I am running into is the owner of the site uses Internet Explorer 11 and the website pages hero images are not showing, but only on Internet Explorer, On every other browser the site looks fine. This site is a WordPress site using a standard theme thats been heavily customized. When I look at the pages code for the hero image area this is what I find:

```
 <img sizes="(min-width: 40em) 80vw, 100vw" srcset="/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/hero-bg.png 375w, /wp-content/uploads/2018/02/hero-bg.png 480w, /wp-content/uploads/2018/02/hero-bg.png 768w" alt="">
```

I added a simple version for testing

```
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/hero-bg.png" >
```

this showed up in explorer so its this code causing the issue.

I dont know how I can fix the issue. Changing the original line of code so that it works on explorer will affect the other browsers.

So Im hoping someone can help figure out if either there is a explorer friendly way of writing this code so that it doesnt affect the other browsers, or is there a way to use a different line of code in the event of explorer being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

srcset attribute is not supported in ie11. The good news is that you can use srcset along with src without problem. ie11 will just ignore the srcset attribute and the rest of the browsers will use srcset instead of src.

Just use this:

```
<img sizes="(min-width: 40em) 80vw, 100vw" srcset="/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/hero-bg.png 375w, /wp-content/uploads/2018/02/hero-bg.png 480w, /wp-content/uploads/2018/02/hero-bg.png 768w" alt="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/hero-bg.png">
```